# How to run tests one by one using just one row from CSV file?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ddt

Hi everyone it's my first post here. I'm learning test automation with Python and I have a problem.

I have a test class, something like that

*test_scenario_1.py*

```
class TestClass:

        @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
        @data(*getdatafromcsvfile("Logins.csv"))
        @unpack
        def test_1(self, logins):
                self.login(logins)

        def test_2(self):
                self.display_name()
```

*Logins.csv*

```
Logins
user_A
user_B
user_C
```

I'm using pytest and when I run *test_scenario_1.py* from terminal *test_1* will be executed 3 times using all of rows from CSV file and then *test_2*. Is any possibility to run second test after first execute of *test_1*?
In simple words I want to login for each of users (form csv file) and display their names one by one.
Do you have any ideas what should I do in that case?

Comment: Maybe use a dictionary to store the names of the users, and then list them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to always keep tests isolated and run them from a clean browser instance. Each test should launch a new browser, run the test, and then close the browser. That ensures that each test starts clean. What if one of your previous tests runs into an error or puts your site into a bad state? Then all the later tests run on that browser instance fail or are otherwise affected by the bad state and may give false positives or false negatives.

Just add the login to the second test. Without any details on what is in `self.login()`, it might not be worth having that as a test any more. Just have a single test that is...

```
def test_1(self, logins):
    self.login(logins)
    self.display_name()
```